# JQuery Mobile Icon Off-Center in Icon-Only Button

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I was wondering if anyone could help me. In a button I have a custom icon placed in a button (eventually I will remove the background) however since changing the size of the icon, it is now off-center. Could anyone explain why this is?

```css
.spot {
    position: absolute;
    /*
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    */
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
}

.image-holder {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    position:absolute;
}

.spot:after {
 background-image: url("img/spot.svg");
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spot-holder">
  <a href="#ashcloud" 
     data-rel="popup" 
     class="spot ui-btn ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"
     data-transition="flip"
     style="top: 50px; left: 250px;"></a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="ashcloud">
    <p>ASH CLOUD</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the top and left margins on the :after pseudo element.

```
.spot:after {
    background-image: url("img/spot.svg");
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L035hf0s/)**